# How to write simple filter in Spring Securtiy MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on my simple REST API prototype written in Spring 3.2. I have read Spring Security documentation and many tutorials on the internet but nothing make sense to me how to secure my REST API.

My requirements are very simple - upon on value of one parameter from HTTP headers I need to allow or disallow client to consume the particular resource. I have a service that can be injected as a bean and this bean can process this task for me. What I need to know is **where** to place this "check" bean and **how** to tell to Spring to use it as a filter before the resource is consumed (I configure my application programmatically via Java class and I don't use applicationContext.xml).

I would be appreciate for some simple example - Spring configuration and filter class.

Comment: Spring Security is overkill for your requirement. Just use a filter or create a interceptor and override the *preHandle* method. Filters can simply be added in your web.xml or `WebApplicationInitializer`.

Answer (score 1):

As Bart said, You can very well make use of interceptor. You can do like

```
     @Component
        public class SecurityFilter extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

            @Override
            public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
                    /*you can do this way. set the response content type as 
                    * 'application/json'.get the PrintWriter from response and print
                    * the Json object
                    */
                     response.setContentType("application/json");
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    /*jsonObject can be either be a String form of json. example:
                    *"{ key1:'value1', key2: 'value2' }" or JSON object created
                    *using JSON libraries like json.org or Gson package
                    */
                    out.print(jsonObject);
                    out.flush();
                return false;
            }

        }
```

You have to also configure in your spring configuration file.

```
    <mvc:interceptors>
            <mvc:interceptor>
               <!-- map the url path to the appropriate filter -->
                <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
                <bean class="com.keerthi.filter.SecurityFilter" />
            </mvc:interceptor>
        </mvc:interceptors>
```

Please read the documentation of [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) API. This will help you

Comment: Yes, Interceptor works for me. But when I return `false` in `preHandle` method, I need to return to the client back JSON with some meta information. How to handle this?